# Activity Indicator in GWT MAP

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2, gwt-ext

What I would like to have is an activity indicator, which is displayed after my app is up and running, but while GWT is making AJAX calls.

For example have a look at following site : http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/#

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to deal with the same kind of stuff few days back. The way I did was, created an Icon and Overlayed on the map.

```
Icon icon = Icon.newInstance("loading.gif"); // load you gif as icon
MarkerOptions options = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
options.setIcon(icon);
Marker indicator = new Marker(point, options);
```

So before the Async call and after you map is up, just add the icon to the map using

```
map.addOverlay(indicator);
```

and after the Async call remove the overlay using

```
map.removeOverlay(indicator);
```

I am not sure how correct this approach is, but this is what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an activity indicator from [here](http://ajaxload.info/), they are animated gifs so you can display one like this:

```
<g:Image ui:field="activityImage"/>

MyResources resources = GWT.create(MyResources.class);
this.activityImage.setResource(resources.activityImage());
```

and in your resources interface you would set the image:

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle{
    // use the actual path to your image
    @Source("../resources/images/activityImage.gif")
    ImageResource activityImage();
}
```

When you make your async calls:

```
loadingImage.setVisible(true);
```

and in the callback:

```
loadingImage.setVisible(false);
```